# Show $\frac{1}{x}$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

From $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$,
how can I go to $|\frac{\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x_0}}{x-x_0} - (-\frac{1}{x_0^2})| < \epsilon$

Comment: What you have written is ❌

Comment: hi: did you mean $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x_0}}{x-x_0} = -\frac{1}{x^2_0}$$ ?

Comment: Sorry, this is correct. I am just asking for the process.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x_0\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_0}}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{x_0-x}{xx_0(x-x_0)}=\lim_{x\to x_0}-\dfrac{1}{xx_0}=-\dfrac{1}{x_0^2}$

If you still want to use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit, then we'll use that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_0}}{x-x_0}=-\dfrac{1}{x_0}\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{1}{x}$ as shown before, so we only need to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{1}{x_0}$.

Take some $\varepsilon>0$. We need $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right|<\varepsilon$. Now, $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right|=\left|\dfrac{x_0-x}{xx_0}\right|=\dfrac{1}{|x_0|}\left|\dfrac{x_0-x}{x}\right|=\dfrac{1}{|x_0|}\dfrac{|x-x_0|}{|x|}$.

Since $x_0\neq0$ we can consider $\delta_1=|x_0|>0$, so if $x$ satisfies $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$ then $x_0-\delta_1<x<x_0+\delta_1$, which implies $x\neq0$. Do you see why? (Consider the cases $x_0>0$ and $x_0<0$).

Therefore $\dfrac{1}{|x|}<M=\dfrac{1}{N}$, where $N=\min\{|x_0-\delta_1|,|x_0+\delta_1|\}$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$. To see this use the previous paragraph and consider the cases $x_0<0$ and $x_0>0$ as before (remember $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is strictly increasing/decreasing for negative/positive values).

Then you can take $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\dfrac{\varepsilon|x_0|}{M}\}$. Since $\delta\le\delta_1$, all $x$ satisfying $|x-x_0|<\delta\le\delta_1$ imply $\dfrac{1}{|x|}<M$.

Then, for $x$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right|=\dfrac{1}{|x_0|}\dfrac{1}{|x|}|x-x_0|<M\dfrac{1}{|x_0|}|x-x_0|<M\dfrac{1}{|x_0|}\dfrac{\varepsilon|x_0|}{M}=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Can you show with $\epsilon$

Comment: Like that clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

$$|\frac{\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x_0}}{x-x_0} - (-\frac{1}{x^2_0})| < \epsilon\\
|\frac{\frac{x_0-x}{xx_0} }{x-x_0} - (-\frac{1}{x^2_0})| < \epsilon\\
|\frac{\frac{-{(x-x_0)}}{xx_0} }{x-x_0} - (-\frac{1}{x^2_0})| < \epsilon\\
|\frac{\frac{-1}{xx_0} }{1} - (-\frac{1}{x^2_0})| < \epsilon\\
|\frac{1}{x^2_0}-\frac1{xx_0}| < \epsilon\\
|\frac1{x_0}||\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac1{x}| < \epsilon\\
|\frac{x-x_0}{x^2_0x}| < \epsilon\\$$ can you take over ?

Comment: This is where I got stuck, how can i choose my $\delta$